# catalog_product_load_after printing more than 1 product's id

Tags: event-observer

`catalog_product_load_after` event is fired when a product loads. I'm pring the ID of the loaded product but it's printing 3-4 product Id's in log.
Here is my code

```
 <events>
                <catalog_product_load_after>
                    <observers>
                        <retailon_productoption>
                            <type>model</type>
                            <class>retailon_productoption/observer</class>
                            <method>catalogProductLoadAfter</method>
                        </retailon_productoption>
                    </observers>
                </catalog_product_load_after>
            </events>
```

Observer code

```
 public function catalogProductLoadAfter(Varien_Event_Observer $observer){
            $product = $observer->getProduct();
            Mage::log($product->getId(), null, 'po.log');
        }
```

Why so? Does recently viewed products or recommended products appearing on product page are affecting it?

Comment: catalog_product_load_after is call every time a product is loaded, therefore if you have multiple products on your page the observer will trigger each time those product are called

Comment: How I can get main product id?

Comment: Can you provide more info on what your trying to accomplish, because if your on a pdp you could use the `Mage::registry('current_product')->getId()`

Comment: I'm designing a custom popup on product page, which will contain product's custom option attribute. So I want to save these attributes in quote(Not sure whether I should save it in quote or not). when I'm on product page and send these values with orders.

Comment: I think it would be better to use a add to cart observer